# Access denied for 'root'@'localhost' but I'm not root

Tags: symfony, root, access-denied

I developed a little management application with Symfony. It works a lot on local. I put it all on my webserver (called Planethoster), and I've got the following message when I try to login in my application using `app.php`:

> SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

But in my parameters.yml file, I have not put the root user, it's another standard user that can only SIUD. I believe that `app.php` does not load my `parameters.yml` or `config.yml` file.

The last but not the least, I can log in using `app_dev.php`. It works but not with `app.php`.

Comment: make sure your database configuration is well set in your parameters.yml , in fact app_dev.php load parameters_dev.yml + parameters.yml and config_dev.yml + config.yml and app.php loads only parameters.yml and config.yml

Comment: Have you cleared the cache for production by using --env=prod ?

Comment: Are you using a shared hosting provider?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Verify your Database settings in app/config_prod.yml for production use.
2. clear your cache by php app/console cache:clear --env=prod

Comment: I've been trying to solve this problem for an hour and everyone is telling me to put the database configuration on 'app/config/parameters.yml' and now I've read your answer and copied the 'parameters.yml' file content entirely to 'app/config_dev.yml' and it worked like a charm...
WTF?
Can you explain me why? I'm using Symfony 2.3.6.
Why is Symfony telling me to configure one file that is ignored?